# Swift child is returning Null when nested or ObserveSingleEvent, returns fine when not nested

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve a child of a child.  the entire snapshotValue returns null. When I retrieve the same data as a child (not nested) it retrieves fine.

I'm Using XCode 10 and Swift 4

To troubleshooting purposes, I have two nodes called 'Promoters'. One at the root and one nested inside a 'Partners' child (preferred). I will remove the top level node when I get the nested node working.

Here is the data structure:

```
"Partners" : {
    "Acts" : [hidden],
    "Promoters" : [ null, {
      "Cell" : hidden,
      "Contact Name" : “hidden”,
      "Email" : “hidden”,
      "Facebook" : “hidden“,
      "Title" : "CHORD Productions"
    } ]
  },
"Promoters" : {
    "chord" : {
      "Title" : "Chord Productions"
    }
  }
```

This retrieves the data I'm looking for (a list of Titles to populate a picker):

```
        let promotersDB = Database.database().reference().child("Promoters")
        promotersDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
            let promoterName = snapshotValue["Title"]!
            let promoter = PromoterClass()
            promoter.promoterName = promoterName
            self.promoterArray.append(promoter)
            let isSuccess = true
            completion(isSuccess)
        }
```

This returns nil:

```
        let promotersDB = Database.database().reference().child("Partners").child("Promoters")
        promotersDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
            let promoterName = snapshotValue["Title"]!
            let promoter = PromoterClass()
            promoter.promoterName = promoterName
            self.promoterArray.append(promoter)
            let isSuccess = true
            completion(isSuccess)
        }
```

I'd prefer observeSingleEvent, but this also returns nil:

```
        let promotersDB = Database.database().reference().child("Promoters")
        promotersDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
            let promoterName = snapshotValue["Title"]!
            let promoter = PromoterClass()
            promoter.promoterName = promoterName
            self.promoterArray.append(promoter)
            let isSuccess = true
            completion(isSuccess)
        })
```

The error is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

**I am using force unwrapping for now to be reviewed at a later date after investigating how much of the data integrity can be done with backend rules :)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it looks like snapshot has the first record, but assigning it to snapshotValue is failing .....po produces this. <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'snapshotValue'
snapshotValue

Answer (score 0):

I think firebase usually suggests the [Fan Out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) method when dealing with data trees, so you shouldn't nest array like "Promoters" anyways.

You'll also want to identify each of the Promoters by a uid instead of by their name (incase you have to change their name in the system).

So if you want, try to restructure your data like this:

```
let uid = Database.database().reference().child("Promoters").childByAutoId()
// uid will be some super long string of random letters and numbers, for example like: 1hjK2SCRV2fhCI0Vv3plGMct3mL2

"Promoters" : {
    "1hjK2SCRV2fhCI0Vv3plGMct3mL2" : {
      "Title" : "Chord Productions"
    }
  }
```

And then when you want to query values within that promoter's branch:

```
let titleRef = Database.database().reference().child("Promoters").child(uid)

titleRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let promoter = PromoterClass()
        promoterName = dict["Title"] as? String
        promoter.promoterName = promoterName
    }
}
```